# Backbone Menu View Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone.js application that looks like:

```js
var StoreView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: ".container",
initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

events: {
    "click #addProduct": "addProduct",
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(render("index"));
},

addProduct: function(){
    var productView = new StoreProductView({
        el: $('#products')
    });
    productView.render();
}
});
```

and my storeProductView.js looks like:

```js
var StoreProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function () {
      this.$el.append(render("products/product"));

      $('.menu').dropit();

      return this;
   },
   events: {
      "click .changeProductType": "changeProductType"
   },
   changeProductType: function (e) {
      alert( e.this.data() );
   }
});
```

Here's the StoreProductView template:

```js
<div class='product'>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a class='changeWidgetType' data-type='model' href="#">Model</a></li>
          <li><a class='changeWidgetType' data-type='color' href="#">Color</a></li>
          <li><a class='changeProductType' data-type='book' href="#">Book</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Basically what happens is when you hit #addProduct, a new StoreProductView is called. Many can be called on one page. Each StoreProductView has a .menu which uses the [DropIt](http://dev7studios.com/dropit/) jQuery plugin to have a dropdown.

I'm having two problems:

1. When you click a link inside the menu, it's supposed to alert what the data type is (so when you click "Model" it should alert *model*). Right now it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`
2. The DropIt menu is only working on the first StoreProductView that is rendered. If you have two StoreProductView's rendered and click the menu of the second nothing happens.

Comment: Why does StoreProductView use `$el.html` instead of `$el.append`? Doesn't a new item overwrite the previous one? Also what is `e.this`? There is no such property.

Comment: Oops, I posted an older version of the code, it should use append instead of html. e.this is my attempt at getting the element that created the event.